# Does instantiating a new class based on prop affect the render performance in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Let's say we have an object which initial state in `redux` is:

```js
const contacts = {
   viewMode: 'basic',
   activeContacts: [
      {id:1,name:'ali',...},
      {...}
   ]
}
```

the reducer's component `Contacts`

```js
class SelectBox {
    constructor(name, options, /** other params */) {
        name: name
        options: options
        // other props
    }
}
class SelectBoxOption {
    constructor({ name, value, /** other params  */ }) {
        name: ''
        // other props
    }
}

class Contacts extends Component {

  render() {

        const { contacts } = this.props

        // option 1 : map the props using a dynamic object

        const selectBox = {
            name: 'contacts',
            options: contacts.map(k => ({
                name: k.name,
                value: k.value,
                /** other props */
            }))
        }

        // option 2 : map using a class

        const selectBox = new SelectBox('contacts', contacts.map(k => new SelectBoxOption(k)))

        return (...);
    }

}
```

My question is, are both options the same? or does `option 1` provide better rendering performance in case of a deep object (by not instantiating a new class each time the component renders)

Comment: Only optimize once you've measured a performance issue. Then, only optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: option 2 to go with if you don't  want to go with hook.

Comment: This is not the suggested way of rendering react components, react use some caching logic when you try to render components using Map. In the above example you have provided the "SelectBoxOption" component will create new instances every time. hence it will cause memory leak issue.

Comment: @Yedu `SelectBoxOption` is not a component.

Comment: Honestly, creating multiple classes to manage simple data like that seems over-engineered. Wait till you need it before isolating this and try to keep the code simple and obvious for yourself and others, which in React is simple literals most of the time.

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice. I agree with @Emile Bergeron. Ideally both option 1 and option 2 should produce same output. When we are writing Javascript we need to think about bundle size as well. If you consider the option 2 will always produce more lines of code which is un necessary in this particular scenario.

Comment: Well, my problem is not with the `bundle size` nor with the `output` or with the `simplicity` but with the `rendering performance` for both options?  @BhojendraRauniyar suggested `option 2`, is there any reason `performance-wise`?

Comment: The performance is negligible in this case. And the only real way to know, is to measure, and results can vary from browser to browser.